# Exchanging objects between 2.78 and 2.80

Tags: export, import, versions

So, I have a scene put together in Blender 2.78 and a model made with Blender 2.80 that I want to use together. I downloaded the scene (version 2.78 required) and made the model myself beforehand. Apparently, I can neither open the older version's file with 2.80, nor the newer version's with 2.78. 
I tried exporting the model from 2.80 to various export formats and import it in 2.78, and vice versa, but that didn't work either. Is there any way you guys know of, how to make this work? I'd be glad, if I wouldn't have to model that all over again.

Comment: Did you try to append the model in the newer version of Blender? Use 2.8 to append the scene into the new file to combine it all together.

Comment: Hey thank you, didn't thought about that. Seems to have worked.